# How to add wow slider on my aspx page

Tags: asp.net, wowslider

I am trying to add wow slider on my aspx page 
What I have tried so far..

I have added the wow slider to an html page copied the contents to aspx page note that aspx and html page are in same directory so its working on my local host but when I upload on server slider doesn't work.
I have searched and found that I need to add engine0 and data folder but in my case I cant find these two folders in wow slider folder.I have wow slider 8.5
I have many folders and .dll files but not **engine and data folder**,where can I find these two folders??
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

publish the wowslider first then it will show you the slide display along with instructions where the engine and data folder are located. usually its located in your c:/user/user... folder path.